# Interactive sorting only for the page being viewed

Tags: reporting-services

I have added interactive sorting to my report.

However I want to sort only the data a specific page: suppose I have 1 to 100 pages, and I am on page no. 10, then I want to sort only page no. 10's data, instead of sorting data for pages 1 to 100.

Is this possible in SSRS?

Comment: I don't believe this is possible using out-of-the box sorting. An alternative might be to return less data (not 100 pages) by allowing users to filter using report parameters - this may lessen the need for sorting.

Comment: Second @thomasswilliams' comment (you should turn that into an answer tbh), this isn't possible out-of-the-box.